# AntD RangePicker custom picker type (period)?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd, daterangepicker

I've been using [Ant Design DatePicker](https://ant.design/components/date-picker) for a while, but now I need to customise it by using custom `picker` prop.

### What I have now

I use a few different RangePickers, one like this among others:

```
<RangePicker picker="quarter" />
```

[image: quarter rangepicker]

### What I need to have

Now, the trouble is I need custom RangePicker such as `<RangePicker picker="bimonth" />` that would allow me to select custom date ranges, so let's say I want it to select not quarters but bimonthly (so every 2 months from given year could be selected), example below:

[image]

Any idea if it's even possible and how do I achieve that? I have tried using `presets` and `cellRender` but I'm afraid those props aren't suitable for my needs and I'm a bit lost.